# Deleteing Rails Record after a specific period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `form` model that I would like to delete records over 90 days old.  I've seen several suggestions of how to do this, but all seem to focus on Rails 3 instead of Rails 4.  Having never used rails 3 and honestly not really up on all the changes, I'm curious if there is a better way to accomplish this, or if a newer gem exists to help.

I'm using Rails 4 with Unicorn.

Comment: *When* do you want to delete those records? Today? Every day? Every hour?

Comment: Important factor I left out - I'd like to do it every day.  If there's a scheduling option, preferably some time with low use, like 3 am!

Comment: You could use a background processing gem like https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Comment: @harsh Intresting.  I've been looking at WHENEVER (https://github.com/javan/whenever), looks like it accomplishes similar tasks

Comment: `whenever` is a good choice, especially if you don't want to mess up with `cron`.

Comment: Would be helpful if you'd mentioned the options you have seen for rails 3, probably some of them are useful for rails 4, too.